# logistic regression - class created with non significant coefficients?

Tags: r, logistic, statistical-significance, aic

I've created an example table (just in order to create a function) with:

```
ex<-data.frame(b=c(rep('A',50),rep('B',30), rep('C',20)), 
fl=round(runif(100,0,1),0),r=runif(100,0,0.5))
ex2<-cbind(ex,model.matrix(~b-1,ex))
lineal<-ex2$bB+ex2$bA*ex$fl+ex$fl
ex$clase<-round(1/(1+exp(-lineal)),0)
```

Then I run a logistic regression model (MASS library)

```
fm<-as.formula(clase~b+fl+r)
modT<-glm(clase~1, family=binomial, data = ex)
modT<-stepAIC(modT, scope = fm, family=binomial, data =ex, k = 4)
summary(modT)
```

As you can see coefficients are not significant, but I've created the class using them. So I don't understand why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: First, you should actually *draw* the outcome rather than round it up (not least to remove the numerical errors), e.g. as `ex$clase <- rbinom(nrow(ex), prob=1/(1+exp(-lineal)), size=1)`.

Comment: Second, you would *not* be surprised to fail to recover the original model and coefficients if you had defined your data as `ex<-data.frame(b=c(rep('A',5),rep('B',3), rep('C',2)), fl=round(runif(10,0,1),0),r=runif(10,0,0.5))`. Maybe ask yourself why that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems, you are not randomizing when creating the dependent variable, and you are using the r variable in the GLM stepwise algorithm (and not when creating the dependent variable). In order to randomize, you need to create a variable that will be 1,0 with `probability = ex$clase` (according to your terminology). You are also running a model with intercept, and there is none defined in the simulation.

If you run this, you will see that the pvalues are almost 0. Some parameter combinations will yield a flatter likelihood, which will end up showing in greater pvalues ( with these ones you will get almost 0 for all of them) - since the stderrors will correspond to the inverse of the information matrix (the curvature of the likelihood)

```
ex <- data.frame(b=c(rep('A',50),rep('B',30), rep('C',20)), 
fl = round(runif(1000,0,1),0),r=runif(1000,0,1))
ex2 <- cbind(ex,model.matrix(~b-1,ex))
ex2$prob <- 1/(1+exp(-2*ex2$fl + ex2$bA + ex2$bB + ex2$bC))

ex2$clase <- ifelse((ex2$r>ex2$prob),1,0)

fm <- as.formula(clase~fl-1 + bA + bB + bC )
modT <- glm(clase~fl-1 + bA + bB + bC , family=binomial, data = ex2)
summary(modT)
modT <- stepAIC(modT, scope = fm , family=binomial, data =ex, k = 4)
summary(modT)
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the absence of a random draw in the dgp. On the other hand the absence of an intercept in the dgp seems unproblematic; it should just be estimated to be zero...

Comment: yep, I solved it with sapply(ex$prob, function (p){rbinom(1,1,p)})